# Acer ASPIRE 5830G WIFI Driver ReInstalled. Still intermittent Connection

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, acer-aspire, wifi-driver

I've WiFi and 2 laptops. internet is ok with one of them but with another connection is sometimes dissapeared.  It is intermittent.
I've already downloaded latest version of wifi driver from [http://support.acer.com/](http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=3677)

but still the connection is problematic. Do you have any ideas or experience? Very thanks in advance!

Comment: It might just be a bad wireless card. If that's the case the only solution would be to get a new card.

Comment: you mean laptop wireless card? I don't even know where is that located. :S

Comment: What kind of laptop is it?

Comment: The wireless card is basically a removable chip inside your laptop that controls your wifi connections. You may have to disassemble it, but if you're up for a challenge, and you read up online, it really isn't that hard. The best advice I can give you if you do this is to remove the battery, the power, turn it off, don't touch or unscrew anything unless necessary, stay off of carpet and avoid socks during installation (think static electricity), and wear a grounded wrist strap. All you will need to do is disassemble until you find the card, and swap it with a new one. I can help you pick one.